# Why will PDFs from TeXworks not print? Will this issue ever be fixed?

Tags: texshop, mactex, texworks, printing

I am fairly new to LaTeX, TeX etc.(I have the latest MacTeX package) and I just recently tried to print out one of my documents made on TeXworks. It would not send any data to my printer. I copy and pasted all my code into TeXShop and it printed. Why is this?

Comment: The PDF viewer in TeXworks doesn't support printing yet, and it usually let's you no about that. But you don't have to compile the document somewhere else, just open the generated PDF.

Comment: I don't think this is a priority in the development of TeXworks (and it's quite difficult, because the program must interface with several different operating systems).

Comment: I don't mean to start an editor war, but ... consider using Texshop instead of Texworks. If you like it better, you won't need work-arounds for this and various other glitches.

Comment: From what I learned about it, there are some issues with the combo Qt framework + poppler (PDF included previewer) + printing under OS X

Answer (score 9):

(CW from comments)

TeXworks is a multiplatform front-end to TeX/LaTeX; its current version is not able to print PDF files on any of the supported platforms.

Whether the situation will change in the future is not known, but the issue doesn't seem to be high priority in the developer's intentions.

Since TeXworks is largely inspired by TeXShop, on Mac OS X it's better to use this one.

Comment: I'm not sure about that last line:TeXshop is actually rather different to TeXworks

Comment: @JosephWright I didn't say they're the same; but it's true that Jonathan Kew draw inspirations from TeXShop when writing TeXworks and I find them quite similar, actually; they differ in extended features (scripting, mainly).